# Real world example of using os.plock?

Tags: python, locking

Are there any real world usages for using [`os.plock`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.plock) from a Python application?

I really can't imagine for what it could be used, not even talking about real world use cases...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing that you would normally use process or memory locking for is to avoid the OS swapping to disk. In the case of a memlock this could be data used for cryptographic purposes that shouldn't be written (even temporarily) to a form of more permanent storage. In the case of a large process, this could also include the processes stack, or other "segments" that should remain only in memory.